# Blender UV Mesh problems

Tags: mesh, uv, sculpting

guys, I'm really new to blender - so I'm hoping this is a rookie mistake. When I try to UV unwrap the face I've sculpted (using Dyntopo) there is a hole where there are no vertices or faces (see photo) 
As a result, when I paint, it does not show up on the face. How do I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Your mesh is way too dense to hope a clean unwrap. You should retopo it first, then do a proper unwrap.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot paint over a hole, so either insert eyeballs as separate objects so you can roll 'm, or fill the gap with topology.